# Can i block access to my network

Tags: router, security, privacy-protection

How can I stop a fellow tenant from hacking my router, and gaining access to all my information - and he keeps changing my passwords.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies, in laymen's terms, we have a tenant on the property whom has his own nbn connection with modem/router (several set-up) however he keeps accessing my devices, changing my passwords, turning of my cameras and God knows what else. How can I protect myself and/or stop this? He's a self named "pro hacker"

Comment: I too have nu own separate network (nbn, modem)

Comment: This is beyond the ability of remote people in a QA forum. You need to hire local professionals who can inspect your systems and secure them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your home or office WIFI router, then you should take a follow up of following few points:

Change the default IP Address scheme of the modem/router
Change the default username / password details and apply a complex one.
You should check for the different access methods like telnet/ssh, these should be disabled.
Some of the devices have option for VPN creation and connectivity, you should also disable that, if someone anonymously configured that.

Above said points are necessary to make your router secure. Additionally, you can reduce the No of users (DHCP) in the device and also the range of WIFI router.

Comment: Might be wise to also force-logout any online data structures - Google, iCloud etc & change passwords there too.

Comment: Thank you. I believe it runs deeper than this, I'm sorry for coming here I just wanted opinions from the best of the best...perhaps i should hire someone to come out and see, any suggestions - Melbourne eastern subs..